# How to close a DB session when opened with Blaze

Tags: postgresql, session, psycopg2, blaze

In the [Docs](http://blaze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sql.html) it was mentioned how to open a connection to a DB with Blaze's **Data**.

```
db = Data('postgresql:///user:pass@hostname')
```

I did like above and then got the following message when I try to do any update operations (like *drop table*) on that DB with a session opened via *Psycopg2* afterwards.

```
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

As I'm making taking care of the sessions that I'm opening with Psycopg2, I suspect this behaviour is because of Blaze. (Please correct, if I'm wrong).

How can I close this Blaze session or connection first when I'm done, so that I can do other stuff with Psycopg2, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in the Blaze mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/blaze-dev/2gulSHuelMc). (Blaze uses *sqlalchemy* to interact with Postgres. By accessing its engine at `db.data`, we can manage our active connections.)